# offchain signing of an erc20 transfer() and avoiding replay attacks

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, replay-attack, off-chain

This is my first question on stackexchange :D

Question:

I'm building a smart contract that matches lenders (of tokens) to borrowers on mainnet.

To avoid gas expenditure, I want the lender to sign an erc20 transfer transaction offchain, I then save that transaction on MongoDB... whenever a borrower is matched to take that loan (which has an interest), Then only is the signed transaction on MongoDB  deployed to mainnet. is this possible? and how could it be done? and if it's possible how can I prevent a replay attack if that transaction is redeployed again to mainnet?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, the problem is that the token's owner won't be able to make any transactions, because the transaction have a nonce. For the tokens that support it you can try using the `permit()` function [EIP-20 approvals via EIP-712 secp256k1 signatures](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612).

Comment: Thanks. this is what was confusing me the nonce. why can't the owner be able to make transactions?

Comment: @codeBull Every transaction has a nonce that is used to order them. They are consecutive numbers starting from 0. Transactions are executed in strictly increasing order. For example if the owner signed a transaction with nonce equal to 8, then he couldn't send a transaction with nonce: 9 until the signed transaction with 8 is executed.

Comment: I really appreciate your time in explaining, thank you. My last question is, if the owner signed transaction 8, which was not broadcasted to mainnet, can he sign another transaction with nonce 8 and broadcast (in this case the first nonce 8 transaction becomes invalid?)?
Thanks again

Comment: @codeBull That is mostly correct. You could attack the blockchain and force a different transaction with the same nonce. Attacks like that are unfeasible after the switch to proof of stake. In practice it is almost impossible to replace a transaction after it appeared in a finalized block.